# Show playa parents of child items listed via {exp:low_alphabet:entries} (not a single entry page)

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic, loop, parent, low-alphabet

Each discography entry has a playa field for each disc that contains all the songs that appear on that record, creating a tracklisting. What I'd like to do is create a reverse navigation system, so that people can browse songs and see all releases they appeared on (albums, singles, collections, etc).

It was straightforward to get Low Alphabet to ouput a page containing all songs starting with a letter, now I'd like to have all parent releases listed under them.

I imagine it's something where I'd need to write some custom PHP or use an embed or stash based on research I've been doing.

Relevant template code below - it just outputs a long list of entries (even for X, which has one song that is included on two discography items). Removing `channel="discography"` doesn't make any impact.

```
{exp:low_alphabet:entries
        channel="songs"
        alpha_ignore="the"
        numbers="before"
        group_numbers="yes"
        numbers_label="#"
        alpha_filter="{segment_3}"
        orderby="title"
        sort="asc"
        disable="categories|member_data|pagination"
        limit="250"
}
     {if low_alphabet_heading}
         <h2>Songs that start with {low_alphabet_label}</h2>
         <ul>
     {/if}
            <li><a href="{url_title_path="songs"}">{title}</a></li>
            {if no_parents}{/if}
                <ul class="list-nav">
                {exp:playa:parents channel="discography"}
                        <li><a href="{path={channel_short_name}/{url_title}}">{title}</a></li>
                {/exp:playa:parents}
                </ul>
        {if low_alphabet_footer}
        </ul>
    {/if}
{/exp:low_alphabet:entries}
```

The following works as expected

```
    {exp:channel:entries channel="lyrics" limit="50"}

         <ul>
            <li><a href="{url_title_path="songs"}">{title}</a></li>
                <ul class="list-nav">
                    {exp:playa:parents}
                    <li><a href="{path={channel_short_name}/{url_title}}">{title}</a></li>
                    {/exp:playa:parents}
                </ul>
        </ul>

    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code should work but you might want to use the [var_prefix parameter](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/templating/module/parents.html) to avoid variable name conflicts.

Also, because Low Alphabet is a plugin and EE's quirky template parser, you'll need to add `parse="inward"` to the opening low_alphabet:entries tag if you're using other tags inside it (as per [the docs](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-alphabet/docs/tags)).

Comment: at this point the playa bit just outputs all songs associated with a discography entry - even for X which only has one song entry, it spits out the latest x discography entries. It's not targeting the "this" entry contained by the loop, but the channel itself as far as I can tell.

Comment: Try adding `entry_id="{entry_id}"` to the playa:parents tag. But this is a Playa issue more than a LA one, really.

Comment: Adding `entry_id="{entry_id}"` makes it so there are no results. I'll give pixel and tonic a ping.

Comment: It does seem to be a LA issue. I'm honestly better off just running a SQL query based on url_segment and manually creating a menu embed if I can get the playa relationships working correctly sticking with a standard channel entries tag.

Comment: Try adding `parse="inward"` to the opening LA tag.